# Why is this bash script not working?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell-scripting

I'm making a bash script which checks the available space on disk:

```
if [ check_space -gt "85" ]; then
echo "removing"
else
echo "not removing"
fi
```

`check_space` returns a number like `52` and the `check_space` function is:

```
check_space() {
df /dev/sda1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//';
}
```

It's returning `./backup.sh: line 63: [: check_space: a full expression was expected` (I translated it from spanish, so that maybe not exact translation). What could be wrong?

Comment: Please re-run the script with LANG=C so that we get the exact error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your condition isn't actually calling check_space, you need something like:

```
if [ `check_space` -gt "85" ]; then
```

Comment: @Ryan, no, this example works perfectly well.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll remove my false doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it...

```
#!/bin/bash

CHECK_SPACE=`df /dev/sda1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//'`;

if [ $CHECK_SPACE -gt "85" ]; then
echo "removing"
else
echo "not removing"
fi
```

I had to pull out my bash cheat sheet. Functions in bash can't return a value, only an exit status.

Comment: Usually, you write the function to print information to stdout, and then capture the output when you invoke the function: `space=$(check_space)`

Answer (score 0):

"85" with the quotes is a string, not a number... -gt will not work.

suggest:

```
CHECK_SPACE=$(df -P /dev/sda1 | awk '$1=="/dev/sda1"{sub("%","");print $5}')

if [ $CHECK_SPACE -gt 85 ]; then
  echo "removing"
else
  echo "not removing"
fi
```